# How do you override a class from a different platform in Lib-GDX?

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx

I am using the [LibGDX-Net](https://github.com/pepedeab/libGDX-Net) project in my project to implement multiplayer support in Libgdx. Some of the classes do not work when using the Libgdx html project since GWT does not support them, so, I would like to uninclude those classes in the html project.

Right now I have created a class with the exact same name in the html project hoping to override the class, but this does not seem to be working.

How could I do this in Libgdx without having to copy the class individually to every platform except html?

For example, I have a class from that library called [WSClient](https://github.com/pepedeab/libGDX-Net/blob/master/prototipo/src/com/jlcm/prototipo/WSClient.java) in my core project. It contains references to the `org.java_websocket` [Java Websocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) library. This library is unusable with GWT, so in my html project I have a class called `WSClient` too and it only contains

```
package com.jlcm.prototipo;

public class WSClient { 

}
```

I am trying to override this class in the html project so it does not reference the `Java Websockets` library. If I try to compile my html project, I get the error that `org.java_websocket` does not exist, even though the class has been overridden in the html project.

It is really weird that this is not working.

Comment: Could you give an example of one of these classes?

Comment: @John Added some examples and further explanation